# Selenium New Instance of Chrome For HTML Button Clicker

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm very new to python and was trying to learn how to make a script that clicks certain buttons on a website.

From my research, it seems that Selenium is a great option. This is the code I've written thus far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('URL')
time.sleep(0.7)

atc = browser.find_element_by_xpath('XPATH')
atc.click()
time.sleep(0.3)

check = browser.find_element_by_xpath('XPATH')
check.click()
```

The program runs fine, and I've removed some specific code

I need Selenium to boot up Chrome but not a new instance of Chrome. I need the script to work on a specific website that needs to be already logged in, so basically through my Chrome Profile.

Question:
Is there a way to get around this problem? From what I know (which is little) the problem arrises from the `webdriver.Chrome`

Is there a way to bypass the `webdriver.Chrome` and use just the `find_element_by_xpath`? Thats really the only reason I need to use this. I don't need to boot up a link from Selenium, just have the script find a button and click it

Thank you!

Edit: 
Would a simple solution be to have my login already in place and have the script run on a separate window so it can bypass the "Please Sign In" page?

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to attach to an existing browser session.

A solution that I've used in the past is to halt the script execution until a key is pressed so I can manually login and get to the expected page.

In Python 3 use `input()`:

```
input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

In Python 2 use `raw_input()`:

```
raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

Comment: This could actually work! How would I write the script to start if I press "Return"?

Comment: It will just continue executing the code that's placed after that line.